# Mongo updateMany statement with date.withZoneSameInstant(xxx)

Tags: mongodb, datetime, mongodb-query, timezone

I have this collection in my Mongo database:

```
id    | place | local time
--------------------------
3     | A     | 12pm
4     | A     | 11pm
5     | B     | 4pm
6     |       | 7pm
```

The local times are stored as ISODates with UTC timezone. A local time of 12 is represented as `2022-01-01T12:00:00.000Z`.

Outside of the database I have a partially complete mapping between places and timezones.

```
place | timezone
A     | Europe/London
B     | Europe/Brussels
```

Using this information I want to make my database rows timezone-aware, by adding new fields that capture the timezone and fix the offset for the date. This would be my ideal result:

```
id    | place | local time | newDate                         | timezone
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
3     | A     | 12pm       | ISODate("2022-07-01T11:00:00Z") | Europe/London
4     | A     | 11pm       | ISODate("2022-07-01T22:00:00Z") | Europe/London
5     | B     | 4pm        | ISODate("2022-07-01T14:00:00Z") | Europe/Brussels
6     |       | 7pm        | ISODate("2022-07-01T07:00:00Z") | UTC
```

Adding the timezone column is straight forward, I iterate over my mapping's table and for each one build a single update statement like this:

```
db.testcollection.updateMany({ place: "A" }, { $set: { "timezone" : "Europe/London" }});
```

Dealing with locations where the timezone for the place isn't known (and we fallback to just using UTC) is also straight forward:

```
db.testcollection.updateMany({ "timezone" : { $exists: false } }, { $set: { "timezone" : "UTC" }});
```

But what I cannot seem to do is apply the timezone change itself, to multiple rows (with the same place) at once, using a Mongo update statement. I'm not entirely sure if it's possible.

I have tried:

```
rs0 [direct: primary] test> db.testcollection.updateMany({ place: "A" }, { $set: { "utctime" : { $dateAdd: { startDate: "$localtime", amount: 1, unit: "hour" }}}});
```

which can change the times by adding/subtracting an hour or so, but actually applying a timezone change like I want is too difficult for `$dateAdd` function. Europe/London has GMT/BST depending on daylight savings, certain years have had and abandoned different historic values: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_by_country

Even a series of time based filter clauses seems incredibly complicated.

The update I want to apply is essentially the same as the Java function:

```
correctUTC = localTimeMarkedAsUTC          // 9pm local time
    .withZoneSameLocal(portTimezone)       // 9pm Europe/London
    .withZoneSameInstant(UTC)              // 8pm UTC
```

I can use the Date object in an update function, but I am still struggling on how I can manipulate `$dateToString` and friends to generate the output I want:

```
test> db.testcollections.updateMany({ place: "A" }, [{ $set: { "utctime" : { $convert : { input: { $dateToString: { date: "$localtime", format: "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z", timezone: "UTC" }}, to: "date" }}}}]);
```

Sets to the same thing it's already set to. Using timezone London merely adds an hour. I want the opposite, which is to subtract an hour from the UTC variant.

Because of the size of the DB, I'd prefer a solution that operates as updates on whole places in bulk, or doesn't use `.forEach(function(e){ ... })` to hit every record, unless that's the last possible solution that can possibly work?

I'm on Mongo 5.0

Comment: For me it is not fully clear what you try to do. MongoDB stores date/time as UTC time - **always and only!**. What you can change, is the **display** of these values, e.g. `{ $dateToString: { date: "$utctime", format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", timezone: "$timezone" } }`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit What I'm trying to do is essentially adding a field, that in Java could be expressed as `myDate.withZoneSameLocal(portsTimezone)`. That turns 7pm UTC into 7pm London/UK, so that I can compare and show the date correctly going forwards in all timezones. Most people, when working with ZonedDateTimes utilise conversion functions like `myDate.withZoneSameInstant(someVal)` which doesn't "fix" my local dates.

Comment: I doubt `12pm` means `ISODate("2022-07-01T11:00:00Z")` while `11pm` should be `ISODate("2022-07-01T22:00:00Z")`. How do you like to handle daylight-saving times? `12pm` does not tell whether you are in summer or winter season.

Comment: MongoDB does not support hours in 12-hour "pm/am" format. You need to use a 3rd party library, e.g. [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/), [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/?id=luxon) or [Day.js](https://day.js.org/en/). In order to update in Bulk, see [db.collection.bulkWrite](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/). However, you should **never** store date values as strings, it's a design flaw. Store always proper `Date` object and localize display in your client.

Comment: Apologises for the simplified write up. In my real scenario I have the full date, e.g. `ISODate("2022-05-06T13:00:00Z")` and its because I know its a local saved as UTC and because I know Place X is `Europe/London` - That's how I know the correct encoding for the UTC should be 12:00:00Z. I just can't get there. The original code wasn't written to be timezone aware but chose to use ISODate formats (as recommended), so it's admittedly wrong, using UTC as a way to ignore them, and this is what I'm trying to correct.

Comment: I don't have a specific client written in JS, I was hoping to perform this correction to UTC values by using mongo-shell and `db.collection.updateMany`. Is it possible to use 3rd Party timezone libraries in mongo/mongosh like this?

Comment: So, if I get you correctly then `ISODate("2022-05-06T13:00:00Z")` is a wrong value and actually means `2022-05-06T13:00:00+02:00` (for "Europe/Brussels") - and you like to update the date to correct value `ISODate("2022-05-06T11:00:00Z")`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Exactly. The operation could be described as Java's `withZoneSameLocal` or you might describe it as "overwriting the timezone without changing the time and then adjusting the timezone back to UTC"
See this: https://ideone.com/iYMI9V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
  {timezone: {$ne: "UTC"} }, // UTC times do not need any correction
  [
    {
      $set: {
        newDate: {
          $dateFromString: {
            // "cut" wrong time zone
            dateString: {
              $dateToString: {
                date: "$newDate",
                format: "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L"
              }
            },
            format: "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L",
            timezone: "$timezone" // "attach" correct time zone
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
)
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AuPzl2YkaVm)

Comment: Happy you for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap it with [] to create a pipeline:

```
db.collection.update({
  place: "A"
},
[{
  $set: {
    "utctime": {
      $dateAdd: {
        startDate: "$localtime",
        amount: 1,
        unit: "hour"
      }
    }
  }
}],
{
  multi: true
})
```

As you can see [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BAMBEcKq7XX).
Which can off course work with a bulk operation