# Mongo updateMany statement with an inner array of objects to manipulate

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm struggling to write a Mongo [UpdateMany](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#mongodb-method-db.collection.updateMany) statement that can reference and update an object within an array.

Here I create 3 documents. Each document has an array called `innerArray` always containing a single object, with a single date field.

```
use test;
db.innerArrayExample.insertOne({ _id: 1, "innerArray": [ { "originalDateTime" : ISODate("2022-01-01T01:01:01Z") } ]});

db.innerArrayExample.insertOne({ _id: 2, "innerArray": [ { "originalDateTime" : ISODate("2022-01-02T01:01:01Z") } ]});

db.innerArrayExample.insertOne({ _id: 3, "innerArray": [ { "originalDateTime" : ISODate("2022-01-03T01:01:01Z") } ]});
```

I want to add a new date field, based on the original date field, to end up with this:

```
{ _id: 1, "innerArray": [ { "originalDateTime" : ISODate("2022-01-01T01:01:01Z"), "copiedDateTime" : ISODate("2022-01-01T12:01:01Z") } ]}

{ _id: 2, "innerArray": [ { "originalDateTime" : ISODate("2022-01-02T01:01:01Z"), "copiedDateTime" : ISODate("2022-01-02T12:01:01Z") } ]}

{ _id: 3, "innerArray": [ { "originalDateTime" : ISODate("2022-01-03T01:01:01Z"), "copiedDateTime" : ISODate("2022-01-03T12:01:01Z") } ]}
```

In pseudo code I am saying take the `originalDateTime`, run it through a function and add a  related `copiedDateTime` value.

For my specific use-case, the function I want to run strips the timezone from `originalDateTime`, then overwrites it with a new one, equivalent to the Java `ZonedDateTime` function `withZoneSameLocal`. Aka 9pm UTC becomes 9pm Brussels (therefore effectively 7pm UTC). The technical justification and methodology [were answered in another Stack Overflow question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71965687/mongo-updatemany-statement-with-date-withzonesameinstantxxx).

The part of the query I'm struggling with, is the part that updates/selects data from an element inside an array. In my simplistic example, for example I have crafted this query, but unfortunately it doesn't work:

This function puts `copiedDateTime` in the correct  place... but doesn't evaluate the commands to manipulate the date:

```
db.innerArrayExample.updateMany({ "innerArray.0.originalDateTime" : { $exists : true }}, { $set: { "innerArray.0.copiedDateTime" : { $dateFromString: { dateString: { $dateToString: { "date" : "$innerArray.0.originalDateTime", format: "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L" }}, format: "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L", timezone: "Europe/Paris" }}});

// output
  {
    _id: 1,
    innerArray: [
      {
        originalDateTime: ISODate("2022-01-01T01:01:01.000Z"),
        copiedDateTime: {
          '$dateFromString': {
            dateString: { '$dateToString': [Object] },
            format: '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L',
            timezone: 'Europe/Paris'
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

This simplified query, also has the same issue:

```
b.innerArrayExample.updateMany({ "innerArray.0.originalDateTime" : { $exists : true }}, { $set: { "innerArray.0.copiedDateTime" : "$innerArray.0.originalDateTime" }});

//output
  {
    _id: 1,
    innerArray: [
      {
        originalDateTime: ISODate("2022-01-01T01:01:01.000Z"),
        copiedDateTime: '$innerArray.0.originalDateTime'
      }
    ]
  }
```

As you can see this issue looks to be separate from the other stack overflow question. Instead of being able changing timezones, it's about getting things inside arrays to update.

I plan to take this query, create 70,000 variations of it with different location/timezone combinations and run it against a database with millions of records, so I would prefer something that uses `updateMany` instead of using Javascript to iterate over each row in the database... unless that's the only viable solution.

I have tried putting `$set` in square brackets. This changes the way it interprets everything, evaluating the right side, but causing other problems:

```
test> db.innerArrayExample.updateMany({ "_id" : 1 }, [{ $set: { "innerArray.0.copiedDateTime" : "$innerArray.0.originalDateTime" }}]);

//output
  {
    _id: 1,
    innerArray: [
      {
        '0': { copiedDateTime: [] },
        originalDateTime: ISODate("2022-01-01T01:01:01.000Z")
      }
    ]
  }
```

Above it seems to interpret .0. as a literal rather than an array element. (For my needs I know the array only has 1 item at all times). I'm at a loss finding an example that meets my needs.

I have also tried experimenting with the `arrayFilters`, documented on my mongo updateMany documentation but I cannot fathom how it works with objects:

```
test> db.innerArrayExample.updateMany(
...    { },
...    { $set: { "innerArray.$[element].copiedDateTime" : "$innerArray.$[element].originalDateTime" } },
...    { arrayFilters: [ { "originalDateTime": { $exists: true } } ] }
... );
MongoServerError: No array filter found for identifier 'element' in path 'innerArray.$[element].copiedDateTime'
test> db.innerArrayExample.updateMany(
...    { },
...    { $set: { "innerArray.$[0].copiedDateTime" : "$innerArray.$[element].originalDateTime" } },
...    { arrayFilters: [ { "0.originalDateTime": { $exists: true } } ] }
... );
MongoServerError: Error parsing array filter :: caused by :: The top-level field name must be an alphanumeric string beginning with a lowercase letter, found '0'
```

If someone can help me understand the subtleties of the Mongo syntax and help me back on to the right path I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to be using [pipelined updates](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/), the issue you're having with the syntax you're using is that it does not allow the usage of aggregation operators and document field values.

Here is a quick example on how to do it:

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "innerArray": {
        $map: {
          input: "$innerArray",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                copiedDateTime: "$$this.originalDateTime"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bozbHhhxAM1)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In my real example, originalDateTime is nested in another object, `timeInfo`. So it looks like this: `applications : [ { timeInfo: { originalDateTime : ISODate(...) }}]`. This means `$mergeObjects` replaces `originalDateTime` and all the other fields entirely when it writes `copiedDateTime`, with this approach. Could I be so kind as to get a variant that works with a nested field please? `$addField`, `$set` and multiple $mergeObjects doesn't seem to work and I'm loathe to open a third stack overflow question for the same query!

Comment: Sure, something like this? https://mongoplayground.net/p/tvFzRgrKcfb

Comment: That's cracked it! Thank you so much for all your time! I'm very grateful.